# Java search for number sequence

Tags: java

Here are the exact words of my project

"Write a class and test program that prompts the user to enter a three-digit number
such that the digits are in order. For example 123, 567. The program will loop until a
correct value is entered. ( 576 is incorrect)"

I have written this program that searches for a specific password but what i need is one that searches for any numerical value where the numbers are in order and im having trouble writing a program that searches for something thats not a specific value, heres what i have so far.

```
         import java.util.Scanner;
         public class pass {
             public static void main(String[] args) {
                 int passw;
                 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                 do {
                     System.out.print("Enter 3 digits in sequence");
                     passw = sc.nextInt();

                     if(passw != 567) {
                         System.out.println("Access Denied");
                     }
                     else {
                             System.out.println("Access Granted");
                     }

                 }
                 while(passw != 567);

             }
         }
```

Comment: Split the problem into parts. Thinking of just mathematics, how do you get the digits of a number in base 10? If you are stuck with that, look up modulus and integer division in Java. After that, how do you check if the three digits are consecutive?

Comment: also i forgot to mention I cannot just ask for 3 seperate numbers, the user will input a 3 digit number and i somehow have to split up that number into 3 digits and check if each digit is consecutive to the last.

Comment: Is the input 147 valid? It says the numbers should be in order, not sure if they need to be adjacent as well.

Comment: no 147 isnt valid they have to be adjacent as well

Comment: @bcsb1001 wow that was so easy I can't believe I missed that, thanks alot

I did 
num % 10 for first number
Num / 10 % 10 for second number
Num / 100 % 10 for third number

Answer (score 0):

You could use a method to check for whether the given digits are in order.

```
private boolean isInOrder(int number){
    int digit = -1;
    while(number > 0){
        if (digit != -1 && digit != (number % 10) + 1)
            return false;  // Since the number is not in order
        digit = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }
    return true;  // If the number is in order
}
```

This method can check whether a number (of any length, not only 3), is in the order specified in the question.

Answer (score -2):

Since you know that your "password" will be an integer with only three digits, you can easily accomplish whether the digits are ordered or not with an if statement. Try out the following code and see if it works for you!

```
public class ThreeDigitPasswordTest {

    public static boolean testPassword(int number) {
        char[] cArr = String.valueOf(number).toCharArray();
        if((cArr[2] == cArr[1] + 1) && cArr[1] == cArr[0] + 1)
            return true;
        return false;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(testPassword(567)); //prints "true"
        System.out.println(testPassword(576)); //prints "false"
    }
}
```

Comment: To OP: if you use this, remember to check if there are exactly 3 digits, and they are in fact digits etc too.

Comment: @notyou Yes, he will need to do that. Although he mentioned having difficulty with the logic of the problem, not about dealing with validating user input. Not sure why I was downvoted considering I provided a working solution.